# angularFire auth.$signOut not triggering .then() function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to return data from my node server and nearly everything seems to work. This code correctly returns data to authenticated users and declines users who are not authenticated or who present an invalid token.

The only thing that is not working is the firebase $signOut function where I would simply like to log when I hit that code. The $onAuthStateChanged is correctly triggering and logging 'Not logged in yet.' But the $signOut doesn't log 'Logging the user out!' like it should. Instead it gives the error that: `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);
app.controller("SampleCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseAuth, $http) {
  var auth = $firebaseAuth();

  $scope.logIn = function login(){
    auth.$signInWithPopup("google").then(function(firebaseUser) {
      console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.user.displayName);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Authentication failed: ", error);
    });
  };

  auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser){
    // can we get back to our server?
    if(firebaseUser) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/secretData',
        headers: {
          id_token: firebaseUser.kd
        }
      }).then(function(response){
        $scope.secretData = response.data;
      });
    }else{
      console.log('Not logged in yet.');
      $scope.secretData = "Log in to get some secret data."
    }

  });

  $scope.logOut = function(){
    console.log(auth);
    auth.$signOut().then(function(){
      console.log('Logging the user out!'); // The only line that doesn't seem to be working
    });
  };
});
```

My understanding of the documentation makes me think that this should work since it is a promise? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut

I also tried to pass it in as a callback, which I don't think is right, and this doesn't throw an error or log the desired console.log

```
auth.$signOut(function(){
  console.log('Logging the user out!'); // The only line that doesn't seem to be working
});
```

Comment: Probably need to change version...see https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/835

Comment: That was easy! Went from 2.0.1 to 2.0.2 and it works! Thank you! Make this an answer and I'll give you some internet points?